# Rules for escaping special characters when using MSDOS 'echo' command to append text to a file?

Tags: escaping, dos, echo

I would like to be able to append any text to a file using the MSDOS command line. AFAIK, the way to do it is with *echo someText>>someFile.txt*

Since *someText* could contain any text, characters like  ***\ & | > < ^*** need to be escaped using the ***^***  Escape character (e.g. \ becomes **^\**)

But it turns out that that's not enough. I've found by experimentation several special cases, and I wonder how to handle some of them (and if there are more like this)

- *echo **D**>>someFile.txt* ,where **D** is any digit. Instead of
  appending **D** to the the file, it outputs "ECHO is on". It's
  necessary to use instead echo **^D**>>someFile.txt. NOTE: When there
  is more characters after the digits it's OK.
- *echo **a=0**>>someFile.txt* appends nothing, just echoes **a=**
- *echo **a=1**>>someFile.txt* inputs just **a=**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with an space between 'digit' and '>>' ?

> echo D >> someFile.txt 
> echo a=1 >> someFIle.txt

it works.but I couldn't find an explanation for that

Comment: Yes, this really works, but it adds a whitespace at the end of the target file, which is not acceptable to my scenario. And I couldn't find an ms-dos command that would delete the last character of a file :)

Answer (score 1):

This is using the digit to indicate what output is required.  Normally 1> directs standard output, 2> directs standard error.  I suppose basically it depends on how the streams are actually programmed in. If the program writes to printer-n then n> will be operative for that stream, else nothing